# successive differentiation isn't working always

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\ln x$

> Find successive differentiate.

$f(x)=\ln x$

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$f'''(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n}$$

That's what I found and what my book wrote. But, I was going to find above values. Then, I noticed I couldn't find $\ln x$ for $0$.

$$f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{0-1}(0-1)!}{x^0}$$
$$=\frac{-\frac{1}{1}(-1)}{1}$$
$$=1$$

But, that wasn't my first function. But, I can find other functions. So, is my successive differentiation wrong? I would request not to suggest me to see Leibniz theorem. Cause, that was too hard for me to understand that's why I am doing Real-Analysis now then, I will learn Leibniz theorem.

Comment: No one says that your formula holds for $n=0$.

Comment: I had written a simple article on Taylor series and Leibniz rule , maybe you will be interested [see here](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

Comment: And yes, this is exactly why you specify what is the interval of $n$ for which the formula is valid

Comment: @ArcticChar ohh, thanks I was thinking the same. But,I couldn't be sure until anyone tells me again thanks

Comment: why do you expect that $(-1)!$ is equal to $-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you have found only works if $n>0$, and so you can say that
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}
\log x &\text{if $n=0$}, \\[4pt]
\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n} &\text{if $n>0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
There's no reason to think the $n$-th derivative can be expressed in terms of a simple formula. This is similar to if you were finding the $n$-th derivative of the function $g(x)=5$. It is perfectly valid to say that $g^{(n)}(x)=5$ if $n=0$, and $g^{(n)}(x)=0$ if $n>0$.